# Starting an android activity from a worker thread?Is this a good practice

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

What i am trying to do over here is that I want to call a webservice and based on its response i might invoke another webservice or start an activity.I am already writing the web service in a separate thread but the issue is that i am calling the activity in a worker thread,
To make myself more clear i have put my **pseudo code**.

```
if (User ID and Password present in the shared preference) THEN 
                 Utils.checkauthorisation(API)   //Web Service Call
                 if(respsonse is Paswordexpired)
                    erase password from DB
                    Goto (LOGIN SCREEN)//startActivity Call
                 else if(download of images hasnt happened today)) THEN
                        UTILS.DownloadImages//Web service call
                        if(response==connectivityorOtherError)
                            Toast respective Message
                            GOTO (GALLERY SCREEN)//startActivity Call
                        else if (response==confilicted Data)
                            Goto (CHANGES SCREEN)//startActivity Call
                        endif
                endif
endif
```

I was planning to show a progress bar and do all these events in a thread like this

```
  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading",
                "Authenticating Please wait.");

     new Thread() {
        public void run() {

        ///execute the pseudo code

                    startActivity(intent); //Is this a good practice

        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = 1;
        messagHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }

    }.start();



            private static Handler messagHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        super.handleMessage(message);
        switch (message.what) {
        case 1:
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

};
```

But something that disturbs me is that  I have to **start an activity in a worker thread** here. **Is this good practice?** I initially thought that we could only start an activity from the UI thread. What is the process happening in the back end here(in the thread sense)? If this is not a good practice what are the other alternatives to implement my pseudocode?

P.S.:Sorry about asking this question again.I had asked the same question earlier but had failed to convey what i wanted exactly so had received answers for alternatives to starting activity on worker thread(part of my question) but didn't recieve any answer on "is this a good practice"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully understand where you're starting the activity, but assuming it's in the "GOTO" lines of your pseudo-code, I would advise you to set the `msg.what` with different values for each activity you want to launch and then launch it on the `handleMessage(Message)`.

This is assumes that the Handler is created in the UI thread. If it's not, you shouldn't dismiss the ProgressDialog as well since both things should be done from the UI thread. Create one on the UI thread and get it there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But doubt is I am able to call startActivity from my worker thread and go to another activity.Are there any issues to doing this?

Comment: It works fine, but it is not recommended as it may lead to task stack problems and may lead to memory leaks as well.